# How to pass value from javascript to php in same page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Im tying to implament a preloader for swf based on this [Post](http://blog.sebastian-martens.de/2010/05/preload-assets-with-javascript-load-complete-callback-for-single-assets-include-swfflash/), but im getting trouble passing the javascript value to a php variable.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

        var swfJSPreLoaderConfig = {

         'assets':['swf/test.swf'],

            'assetLoaded': function( asset){

             alert(asset);

            },}

    </script>
```

The `alert` in the above code shows only when the swf file  `test.swf` is fully downloaded. the value that im trying to get in php is `asset` ( this value contain the swf file path, in this example is `swf/test.swf`. the alert fires always when the swf files is fully dowloaded and it works very good.)

i tried something like this to get it in a php variable. but no lucky.

```
$filename = $_REQUEST['asset'];
```

also i tired using ajax but nothing.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

     var swfJSPreLoaderConfig = {

       'assets':['swf/test.swf'],

         'assetLoaded': function( asset){   

                $.ajax ({ 
                type: "post",
                url: "index.php",
                data: { 'asset': asset },
                success: function()
                    {
                        alert(asset);
                    }
                });

            },}

    </script>
```

and then

```
 $filename = $_REQUEST['asset'];
```

Whats worng?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
data: { 'asset': asset },
success: function(response)
     {
        alert(response);
     }
```

instead of,

```
  data: { 'asset': asset },
  success: function()
        {
          alert(asset);
        }
  });
```

PHP:

```
 echo $filename = $_REQUEST['asset'];
```

Comment: Create new page `assets.php` in that page you add this `echo $filename = $_REQUEST['asset'];` and update that page name in `$.ajax` url parameter!

Comment: the alert shows the value of `asset`  but no echo of variable

Comment: Yes, it should print the value of the `asset`.

Comment: thank your for your help but after doing all the steps you requested no echo of `echo $filename = $_REQUEST['asset'];` in `index.php` . im getting mad now.

Comment: Things are, You can't pass the javscript value into php variable, using ajax you can embed the php output into html using some selector.

Comment: What you want to do after `assetLoaded` function? so that i can help you more on this!!

Comment: i want to show the swf file in object, i added the swf object in a div wich contain a loading gif  background image, and when the asset loaded is loaded i wanted to echo the value in swf object like this `<embed src="<?php echo $filename; ?>.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="650" height="400"  bgcolor="#000000">` i in this mode i create a preloader

Comment: Add `id` attribute in embed tag, in $.ajax success add this - $("yourid").attr('src' response);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45753/discussion-between-mwweb-and-krish-r)

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
url: "index.php"
```

to

```
url: "index.php?asset="+asset
```

Then in PHP, use:

```
echo $_GET['asset'];
```

to confirm that you are sending the correct value

Comment: why do you want to change the `POST` method to `GET` ?

Comment: Didn't see that he was sending it in the data field. Then his code was already working, except that he didn't use an echo to see it. Also the alert should be using the value from the callback, not the original asset value.